# App crashes while calling LocationUpdatesService with permission with NullPointerException

Tags: android

I' trying to implement Google's android foreground location sample from [github](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/LocationUpdatesForegroundService) in my application. It works fine in the first run of the application. It requests for location permission and when the user grants permission, the service is starting flawlessly and fetches location.

But when the app runs the next time while it already has the permission, it crashes by showing a NullPointerException. I'm not able to narrow down the problem. What is different in the second run of the app which already has the permission? Getting error in `OnStart()` in `mService.requestLocationUpdates();` line.
Does it has to do anything with the package name that is declared in the LocationUpdatesService? or is it something else with permission? or with binding?

**Stacktrace**

```
2020-10-21 11:58:04.346 31805-31805/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 31805
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.testapp.LocationUpdatesService.requestLocationUpdates()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testapp.EventsActivity.onStart(EventsActivity.java:237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7348)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at 

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
            at 

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1950)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
2020-10-21 11:58:04.367 31805-31805/com.example.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31805 SIG: 9
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    
        //Location
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        // Used in checking for runtime permissions.
        private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
        // The BroadcastReceiver used to listen from broadcasts from the service.
        private MyReceiver myReceiver;
        // A reference to the service used to get location updates.
        private LocationUpdatesService mService = null;
        // Tracks the bound state of the service.
        private boolean mB

ound = false;
    // Monitors the state of the connection to the service.
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        // Check that the user hasn't revoked permissions by going to Settings.
        if (Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
            if (!checkPermissions()) {
                requestPermissions();
            }
        }
        ....
        .....
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            mService.requestLocationUpdates(); //CRASHING HERE
        }
        // Bind to the service. If the service is in foreground mode, this signals to the service
        // that since this activity is in the foreground, the service can exit foreground mode.
        bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mBound) {
            // Unbind from the service. This signals to the service that this activity is no longer
            // in the foreground, and the service can respond by promoting itself to a foreground
            // service.
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        return  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
                mService.requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                //setButtonsState(false);
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiver for broadcasts sent by {@link LocationUpdatesService}.
     */
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationUpdatesService.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            if (location != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Utils.getLocationText(location),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
    }





    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocationUpdatesService.ACTION_BROADCAST));
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(getBooleanFromSP("logOutBtnClicked")){
            stopService();
            mService.removeLocationUpdates();
        }else if(!getBooleanFromSP("logOutBtnClicked")){
            startService();
            mService.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

}
```

**LocationUpdatesService.java**

```
public class LocationUpdatesService extends Service {

    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
            "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdatesforegroundservice";

    private static final String TAG = LocationUpdatesService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * The name of the channel for notifications.
     */
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

    static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = PACKAGE_NAME + ".broadcast";

    static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".location";
    private static final String EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION = PACKAGE_NAME +
            ".started_from_notification";

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    /**
     * The identifier for the notification displayed for the foreground service.
     */
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;

    /**
     * Used to check whether the bound activity has really gone away and not unbound as part of an
     * orientation change. We create a foreground service notification only if the former takes
     * place.
     */
    private boolean mChangingConfiguration = false;

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    /**
     * Contains parameters used by {@link com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi}.
     */
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
     */
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    /**
     * Callback for changes in location.
     */
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    private Handler mServiceHandler;

    /**
     * The current location.
     */
    private Location mLocation;

    public LocationUpdatesService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };

        createLocationRequest();
        getLastLocation();

        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
        handlerThread.start();
        mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
            // Create the channel for the notification
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
        boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
                false);

        // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
        if (startedFromNotification) {
            removeLocationUpdates();
            stopSelf();
        }
        // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mChangingConfiguration = true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) comes to the foreground
        // and binds with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground service
        // when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onBind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) returns to the foreground
        // and binds once again with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground
        // service when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onRebind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Last client unbound from service");

        // Called when the last client (MainActivity in case of this sample) unbinds from this
        // service. If this method is called due to a configuration change in MainActivity, we
        // do nothing. Otherwise, we make this service a foreground service.
        if (!mChangingConfiguration && Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting foreground service");

            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
        return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    /**
     * Makes a request for location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
     * {@link SecurityException}.
     */
    public void requestLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
     * {@link SecurityException}.
     */
    public void removeLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Removing location updates");
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            stopSelf();
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link NotificationCompat} used as part of the foreground service.
     */
    private Notification getNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

        CharSequence text = Utils.getLocationText(mLocation);

        // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

        // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
        PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, EventsActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                        activityPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                        servicePendingIntent)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentTitle(Utils.getLocationTitle(this))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker(text)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private void getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                mLocation = task.getResult();
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
        }
    }

    private void onNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New location: " + location);

        mLocation = location;

        // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
        if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Sets the location request parameters.
     */
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Since this service runs in the same process as its
     * clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocationUpdatesService getService() {
            return LocationUpdatesService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this is a foreground service.
     *
     * @param context The {@link Context}.
     */
    public boolean serviceIsRunningInForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (getClass().getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                if (service.foreground) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your mFusedLocationClient I think its null

Comment: @AsadAli I didn't change the LocationUpdatesService code to have a issue with `mFusedLocationClient`. Its working fine in app first run. It will prompt permission, and on click  of 'allow' it works fine. The issue comes only from the second start of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else if (mService != null) { // add null checker
            mService.requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        // Bind to the service. If the service is in foreground mode, this signals to the service
        // that since this activity is in the foreground, the service can exit foreground mode.
        bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

Also:

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mService.requestLocationUpdates(); // also request it here
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank a lot. It worked. I don't understand why it is null. It is working in the sample downloaded from github. But not the same code in my app. Strange.

Comment: The initial value for `mService` is null. **mService** is initialized inside `onServiceConnected`, to `onServiceConnected` be called we need `bindService` in `onStart`. So, **requestLocationUpdates** is called inside the `onStart` method, before calling `bindService` and before initializing `mService`. Therefore, we must check for null and call requestLocationUpdates when the mService is ready.

Answer (score 0):

### Update code to this code mService is null because you are initilaizing it after   mService.requestLocationUpdates();

```
 @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        
                if (!checkPermissions()) {
                    requestPermissions();
                } else {
 bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    mService.requestLocationUpdates(); //CRASHING HERE
                }
                // Bind to the service. If the service is in foreground mode, this signals to the service
                // that since this activity is in the foreground, the service can exit foreground mode.
               
            }
```

Comment: Its still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   bindService(Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService::class.java), mServiceConnection!!,
            BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

This code does the trick but somewhere on stackoverflow the preceding code reads like so

```
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        request_permission()
    } else{
        mService!!.requestLocationUpdates()
    }
```

without the elseif that checks the nullability of the mService - this is the variable that needs to be initiated